# bind_param getting an error (seems illogical to me)

Tags: php, mysqli, bind

This doesn't seem to make sense to me. Is this ACTUALLY wrong??? I've looked at other people's work, and they have that same type of bind_param  as me, like in this example:

[php, mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728824/php-mysqli-stmt-bind-param-number-of-elements-in-type-definition-string-doesn)

I have 23 here, AND 23 values (yes, I counted individually, even pressing enter on dreamweaver to make sure). And to be safe, I even tried with 46:

```
$stmt= $con->prepare("INSERT INTO form_corpo_test (compagnie, telephone, site_web, texte_fr, texte_en, categories, profil_exposant, stands_du_manufacturier, pourcentage_quebec, pourcentage_canada, pourcentage_usa, pourcentage_autre, exporte, exporte_souhaite, produits_vert, nouveau_produits, nom, courriel, telephone_ressource, personne_ressource_c_toi, autre_personne_ressource, autre_courriel, autre_telephone)
VALUES
('$_POST[company]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[website]','$_POST[messagefr]','$_POST[messageen]','$str','$_POST[profession]','$_POST[manufacturiers_stand]','$_POST[percent_quebec]','$_POST[percent_canada]','$_POST[percent_usa]','$_POST[percent_autre]','$_POST[bt_export]','$_POST[bt_export_souhaite]','$_POST[bt_prod_verts]','$_POST[bt_new_prod]','$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[resource_phone]','$_POST[personne_ressource]','$_POST[backup_name]','$_POST[backup_email]','$_POST[backup_phone]')");



$stmt->bind_param("sssssssssssssssssssssss", $compagnie, $telephone, $site_web, $texte_fr, $texte_en, $categories, $profil_exposant, $stands_du_manufacturier, $pourcentage_quebec, $pourcentage_canada, $pourcentage_usa, $pourcentage_autre, $exporte, $exporte_souhaite, $produits_vert, $nouveau_produits, $nom, $courriel, $telephone_ressource, $personne_ressource_c_toi, $autre_personne_ressource, $autre_courriel, $autre_telephone);
```

And then I tried this (since phone numbers are integers)

```
sissssssiiiissssssisssi
```

Both outputs THIS error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of
>   variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in
>   /home/product/public_html/sidim.com/formulaires/processForm-test.php
>   on line 77

**EDIT 3**

I have this at the moment:
$con->query("INSERT INTO form_corpo_test SELECT * FROM *");

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO form_corpo_test VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$stmt->bind_param('sissssssiiiissssssisssi', $compagnie, $telephone, $site_web, $texte_fr, $texte_en, $categories, $profil_exposant, $stands_du_manufacturier, $pourcentage_quebec, $pourcentage_canada, $pourcentage_usa, $pourcentage_autre, $exporte, $exporte_souhaite, $produits_vert, $nouveau_produits, $nom, $courriel, $telephone_ressource, $personne_ressource_c_toi, $autre_personne_ressource, $autre_courriel, $autre_telephone);   // bind $compagnie etc. to the parameter
```

This still errors this outputs

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in
>   /home/product/public_html/******/*******/processForm-test.php on line
>   83

This refers to this:

```
$stmt->bind_param('sissssssiiiissssssisssi', $compagnie, $telephone, $site_web, $texte_fr, $texte_en, $categories, $profil_exposant, $stands_du_manufacturier, $pourcentage_quebec, $pourcentage_canada, $pourcentage_usa, $pourcentage_autre, $exporte, $exporte_souhaite, $produits_vert, $nouveau_produits, $nom, $courriel, $telephone_ressource, $personne_ressource_c_toi, $autre_personne_ressource, $autre_courriel, $autre_telephone);   // bind $compagnie etc. to the parameter
```

If there is anything wrong so far, lemme know by all means. I will check out u_mulder's posts more in depth now.

Comment: why are you preparing query with unprocessed `$_POST` values? If this is the actuall code then its fairly obvious why you get that warning message: you don't have any `?` in query, since you are putting values directly

Comment: Also, use strings and not undefined constants to get array values, and wrap variables in `{}` when using directly inside `""` double quotes strings... bad: `" $_POST[company] "` good: `" {$_POST['company']} "`

Comment: Have you read how to bind params properly?

Comment: @Ivan Hušnjak, not obvious for an integrator I'm afraid. So far, I've wrapped them in {}. Concerning the undefined comment, by taking the variables directly from the form, are they not therefore defined? How would you process the $_POST values? I am posting a edit for now, until I read more from u_mulder

Comment: @u_mulder,I thought I did. But, I might have misunderstood, alas.

Answer (score 0):

In [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) it is shown how to bind params:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO CountryLanguage VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);
```

See that question marks? Every question mark will be replaced with a parameter from `bind_param`. So, your query should look like:

```
$stmt= $con->prepare("INSERT INTO form_corpo_test (compagnie,... autre_telephone) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ....."); // 26 ?-signs
$stmt->bind_param("sssssssssssssssssssssss", $compagnie, $telephone.. ); // your params here
```

Comment: Something urgent came up. I will come back tomorrow to look in depth about what you have written.  I can't wait lol. I wish I could have looked at what you wrote, tonite more in depth.

Comment: Now I have a different error showing up. Unless I am misunderstanding both the manual and you, something is wrong that I'm clearly overlooking. I'm still working at it though... If you'd like to further look at it, do so by all means.

Comment: Once again - **where is question signs in your query**?

Comment: We've had a rush here, so I've only been able to look at it today. I've taken a look at it and modified certain errors I saw. As for your question:

$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO form_corpo_test VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");